# WPF text control only updating within dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, I have a linear layout that holds dynamically added user controls. These controls are labeled 1, 2, 3 etc. as they're added. Each control has its own button to remove it from the layout. I am trying to update the numbering as the user controls are added/removed; however, the labels within the user controls aren't updating. The following code is what I'm using to update the labels:

```
private void UserControlThingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DecreaseSmeCount();
        foreach (object child in smePanel.Children)
        {
            if (child is SMEInfoUserControl)
            {               
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() =>
                {
                    (child as SMEInfoUserControl).SMENumber = "test";
                    MessageBox.Show((child as SMEInfoUserControl).SMENumber);
                }), DispatcherPriority.Normal);                 
                MessageBox.Show((child as SMEInfoUserControl).SMENumber);
            }
        } 
    }
```

The text field of the labels update to "test" within the dispatcher, but changes back to its original text after the dispatcher (the first message box shows test while the second shows the original text). Thanks for the help!

Comment: See [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke?view=netcore-3.1). `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` executes a delegate **asynchronously** on the thread the `Dispatcher` is associated with.

Comment: I see, how should I go about updating the label text?

Comment: `SMENumber ` is a property that update labels or not, it's just a string field? how you update labels?

Comment: SMENumber is binded to the text field of a textblock.

Answer (score 0):

[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke?view=netcore-3.1) executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread the `Dispatcher` is associated with. so in your code you get two value. one "test" and another is the original value of `SMENumber`, becuse message boxes shown asynchronously with each other and there are no guarantee which one ("test" or original) will be displayed first.

So to make your code working use `async` and `await`. as bellow: (This code just show that the `SMENumber` update correctly).

```
private async void UserControlThingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DecreaseSmeCount();
    foreach (object child in smePanel.Children)
    {
        if (child is SMEInfoUserControl control)
        {   
            await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() =>
            {
                control.SMENumber = "test";
                MessageBox.Show(control.SMENumber);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Normal); 
            MessageBox.Show(control.SMENumber);
        }
    } 
}
```

Both message boxes must show "test".

For update textBlocks ensure your binding work properly and use this code:

```
private void UserControlThingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DecreaseSmeCount();
    foreach (object child in smePanel.Children)
    {
        if (child is SMEInfoUserControl control)
        {   
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() =>
            {
                control.SMENumber = "test";
            }), DispatcherPriority.Normal); 
        }
    } 
}
```

If your binding will be ok, textBlocks must be updated.

I hope this help you to solve your problem.